# Grails 3 Spring Security override login form

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I've found a few things from spring documentation that you can override the login controller and form. I just want to override the login form itself while keeping the default controller. I found this:

> In the grails security plugin, the login gsp page is located at grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp and the controller at grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy. I don't think the controller can be overwritten by simply creating your own implementation, but you should be able to override the gsp page by placing your own auth.gsp in the same path shown above, in your app.

https://plus.google.com/117486613280979732172/posts/cvqcfAQVWE6

However, this is just not working to override the page and the default page keeps coming up. Has anyone done this with Grails 3 and spring security libraries?

EDIT:
I'm using OAuth2 by using these libraries and setting up my own beans. I think the other way might be to use grails plugins for spring security. Is there a way to override the login page using these libraries?

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.8.RELEASE"
```

Comment: worked for me from within https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/tree/master/grails-app/views/login plugin. Try enabling spring security debugging to see if there are any issues hitting your local pages.

Comment: It works for us. Just defining new `auth.gsp` file in your project in proper path - `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp` does the trick. I have seen some problems if your `auth.gsp` is in your custom plugin which then is used by application, but if you have it in app, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since I'm not using the grails spring security plugin, I needed to replace the login page by the guidance here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

Essentially, I had to create a LoginController

```
class LoginController {
def auth() {

}

def error() {

}
```

Then, I placed the views in the respective paths: views/login/auth, views/login/error

Here is a sample auth.gsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="banner">Login to Security Demo</h1>
<form name="f" action="/login/auth"
      method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden"
           name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in configuration of the HttpSecurity:

```
    @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage('/login/auth')
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login/error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
}
```

It would be nice to use the grails security plugin but I couldn't figure out how to use OAuth2 with it. If anyone has guidance on that, I'd change my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simpler and systematic approach to this. Without all of this manual copy-paste labor.

1. After installing **[spring-security-core plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/index.html#installation)**, use the `grails s2-quickstart` command on grails console to configure basic user and role domain (you can configure other aspects with the s2-quickstart );
2. Install **[spring-security-ui plugin](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/latest/#installation)** and use `grails s2ui-override auth` command to override the **login/auth** form (this will create the login form so that you override it)
3. Use `grails s2ui-override layout` to override the layouts for the form(this will create the springSecurityUI.gsp layout so that you override it)

Hope it helps.